# How do I force the Grid to redraw in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a function that performs some operations on every cell in a column of my grid. The function sets the background color of the cell (`SetCellBackgroundColour`) based on the results of the operation. My issue is that when the function is complete, the cells remain unchanged. On OSX, only when I scroll down do the cells redraw and appear with color. On windows they don't even redraw then, and I have to select and deselect the cells before they get colored.

How do I force the Grid control to redraw and appear correctly after changing cell background colors?

---

#### What I've tried

I've tried to call `Layout()` on the grid, and on the grid's parent panel, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after searching a bit more through [the API](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.Grid-class.html). I found the method `Grid.ForceRefresh` that worked perfectly. Just need to call it once after I'm done editing the grid.